# When I change the display name for a user in AD the saved value does not change in SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user-accounts

When I change the display name for a user in AD the saved value does not change in SharePoint 2013.
I created fields Person / groups in a list when I'm entering the correct name appears like this in AD, but when it is displayed in dispform, the disply name of the field value is shown with old value, for example

My name was registered in AD as Tarciso and was changed in AD to Tarcisio, but SharePoint is still showing Tarcisio

How can the data changed in AD reflect in SharePoint?

Comment: If SharePoint is showing Tarcisio then it's already updated :)

Comment: did you run User PRofile Sync ( full or Incremental Crawl) after making the changes?

Comment: Excuse-me, he is showing Tarciso instead of Tarcísio.
Will I have run User Profile Sync everytime I change a name on AD?

Answer (score 3):

When ever you make a change in AD for one user or all users, You have to run the User Profile Sync Crawl.

You can schedule it daily /weekly or what ever. We schedule incremental every night so that all the changes imported from AD to SharePoint.Run Full Profile Import once a month.